# Setting up Auth Provider with SSO

Tags: rest-api, single-sign-on, namedcredentials, auth-provider

I am calling a REST API using Auth provider and Named credential, but the client wants to use their IDP SSO instead of using API credentials. Is there a way we can configure an SSO with Auth Provider so that the authentication works with the user's IDP credential instead of API credential?

Comment: When you add named credentials you can specify custom auth provider and start the flow there and then?
If they support OIDC then it is pretty easy to implement